# Why does my main.cpp not print anything from my header file

Tags: c++

I have created my header files and `main.cpp`.

From my understanding, you are supposed to create your class and functions in your `shapeMaker.h` file then put functionality in `shapeMaker.cpp` and lastly class the class and its object to print its value to the screen.

However, when I do this on repl.it nothing prints to the screen.

The code does not crash or scream any errors which shows everything is connected right. However, I am met with a blank screen when I press run. Even something such as `cout << "hello world"` won't display. How would I run this code to display on the screen?

**ShapeMaker.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ShapeMaker {

  private:

  int width = 5;
  int height = 5;
  char symbol = '*';

  protected:

  int returnCanvasWidth(int);
  int returnCanvasHeight(int);
  char returnDrawSymbol(char);
  void setCanvasHeight(int);
  void setDrawingSymbol(char);

  public:

  void drawMidCanvasHorizontal();
  void drawMidCanvasVerticalLine();
  void drawCanvasWidthSizeFilledSqaure();
  void drawCanvasWidthSizedSmilingFace();

};
```

**ShapeMaker.cpp**

```
#include "ShapeMaker.h"

int ShapeMaker::returnCanvasWidth(int width){
  std::cout << width;
  return width;
}

int ShapeMaker::returnCanvasHeight(int height){
  std::cout << height;
  return height;
}

char ShapeMaker:: returnDrawSymbol(char symbol){
  std::cout << symbol;
  return symbol;
}

...
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ShapeMaker.h"

int main() {
  ShapeMaker s;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only invoke `ShapeMaker`'s empty constructor and destructor, which you did not implement (so the default implementations are used). So why should you expect that something is printed in `main`?

Comment: Furthermore, these `return_` member methods of `ShapeMaker` do not use the member variables of `ShapeMaker`. A bit odd, don't you think?

Comment: **Even something such as cout << "hello world" won't display.** If you never execute those commands, the terminal is not going to greet you with "hello world".

Comment: Using markdown and doing formatting is not easy especially if you are not used to it. But there is a preview so you see if it works or not. And you should make use of it. The reason for that is if you expect someone to invest the spear time to answer the question then it is expected by you to at least bring it into a readable form. And  readable questions are more likely to be asked.

Answer (score 2):

**Problems**:

- You only invoke `ShapeMaker`'s empty constructor and destructor, for which you did not provide an implementation yourself (so the default implementations are used), in the `main` method. So obviously nothing will be printed by your program in `main`.
- **Even something such as cout << "hello world" won't display.**: If you never execute those commands, the terminal is not going to greet you with "hello world".

**Solution**:

In order to output `"hello world"` in your current example without changing your `main` method do:

Add your own default constructor declaration

```
public:
ShapeMaker();
```

to `ShapeMaker.h`.

Add your own default constructor definition

```
ShapeMaker::ShapeMaker() { 
    std::cout << "hello world";
}
```

to `ShapeMaker.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

You have just created shape object and since there is no constructor function with something to print, you should have to call a member function to print something.

You can call member function like below:

```
s.drawMidCanvasHorizontal();
```

By the way , I can't see any implementation of drawMidCanvasHorizontal() function, so you should have to write it's purpose first.